# How to implement sort of string by using c#.net(MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-views

I'm practicing MVC View by myself, and I've been trying to sorting the data array by using fields `Chapter` (its a string type).

If I using `orderby row.Chapter asccending`, it will be

```
10.1
8.1
9.1
```

But I hope it will be

```
8.1
9.1
10.1
```

So I've been using `orderby float.Parse(row.Chapter) descending` to achieve the expected.

```
@{
    var originalRows = new[]{
        new{
            Title="Title1",
            Chapter="8.1",
            Description="NA"
        },
        new{
            Title="Title2",
            Chapter="9.1",
            Description="NA"
        },
        new{
            Title="Title3",
            Chapter="10.1",
            Description="NA"
        }
    };

    var rows =
        from row in originalRows
        orderby float.Parse(row.Chapter) descending
        select row;
}
<br />
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2' style='font-weight:bold;text-align:left;'>
                    INFORMATION:
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            for (var i = rows.Count(); i-->0;)
            {
                var row = rows.ElementAt(i);

                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        <b>@(row.Title)<br /></b>
                        <b>@(row.Chapter)<br /></b>
                        <pre>@(row.Description)</pre>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr height='0'>
                <td width='50%' style='border:none'></td>
                <td width='50%' style='border:none'></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there any other way is more better to achieve?

Comment: Seems to be working as expected **[here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/54LNEC)**

Comment: I would propose using OrderBy overload which accepts IComparer and adding comparer there. Just because I could imagine the chapter number can contain any number of dots, e.g. 1.45.3, etc. and with custom comparer you can define sort order easily

Comment: @Viktor Arsanov I think the method you mentioned may be what I want, but I have no idea how to use it in my case. Because I don't have other fields to comparer to Chapter. Maybe I am thinking wrong?

Comment: @Annie, I think you do it right; and right now what you do is fine; my answer was rather about future improvements. Regarding the fields to compare and custom comparer - I mean if you have chapter as set of numbers separated  by dot, then you could split it and compare one by another.

Comment: The duplicate will show you about the `Version` type. Store your `Chapter` as a `Version`, then you can order on it as per  `var rows =
        from row in originalRows
        orderby row.Chapter ascending
        select row;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have now is correct for this case. However I think you could reorganize the code to use custom comparer. In other words, what you have now would look like

```
int CompareFloat(string a, string b)
{
    return float.Parse(a).CompareTo(float.Parse(b));

}

var list = new[] { "1.5.47","4.5","5.6","6.6" };

var comparer = Comparer<string>.Create(CompareFloat);

var result = list.OrderBy(i => i, comparer).ToList();
```

Why doing so? Because here you can improve comparison logic. E.g. float.Parse will fail on parsing 1.5.47, while with your custom comparer you could change it to something like

```
int Compare(string a, string b)
{
    var aV = a.Split('.');
    var bV = b.Split('.');

    if (aV.Length != bV.Length)
        return aV.Length.CompareTo(bV.Length);

    for(var i = 0; i < aV.Length; i++)
    {
        var comparisonResult = Int32.Parse(aV[i]).CompareTo(Int32.Parse(bV[i]));

        if (comparisonResult != 0)
            return comparisonResult;
    }

    return 0;

}

var list = new[] { "1.5.47","4.5","5.6","6.6" };

var comparer = Comparer<string>.Create(Compare);

var result = list.OrderBy(i => i, comparer).ToList();
```

But in general what you do is correct - I don't see any advantage on e.g. using decimal instead of float - taking into account which numbers you expect to have as chapter numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
originalRows.OrderBy(row => decimal.Parse(row.Chapter.Replace(".",","))).ToList();
```

Comment: I have been trying it, but it has been no order, thank you.

Comment: @Annie, you need OrderByDescending method, not Order, since you say descencing order works for you.